# RunUMAP gives segmentation fault

Tags: r, runumap

I tried the following

```
> my.exp <- RunUMAP(my.exp, dims = 1:30)
UMAP(a=None, angular_rp_forest=False, b=None, init='spectral',
   learning_rate=1.0, local_connectivity=1, metric='correlation',
   metric_kwds=None, min_dist=0.3, n_components=2, n_epochs=None,
   n_neighbors=30, negative_sample_rate=5, random_state=None,
   repulsion_strength=1.0, set_op_mix_ratio=1.0, spread=1.0,
   target_metric='categorical', target_metric_kwds=None,
   target_n_neighbors=-1, target_weight=0.5, transform_queue_size=4.0,
   transform_seed=42, verbose=True)
Construct fuzzy simplicial set
     0  /  14
     1  /  14
     2  /  14

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xfffffffffffffffa, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)
 2: umap$fit_transform(as.matrix(x = object))
 3: RunUMAP.default(object = data.use, assay = assay, n.neighbors = n.neighbors,     n.components = n.components, metric = metric, n.epochs = n.epochs,     learning.rate = learning.rate, min.dist = min.dist, spread = spread,     set.op.mix.ratio = set.op.mix.ratio, local.connectivity = local.connectivity,     repulsion.strength = repulsion.strength, negative.sample.rate = negative.sample.rate,     a = a, b = b, seed.use = seed.use, metric.kwds = metric.kwds,     angular.rp.forest = angular.rp.forest, reduction.key = reduction.key,     verbose = verbose)
 4: RunUMAP(object = data.use, assay = assay, n.neighbors = n.neighbors,     n.components = n.components, metric = metric, n.epochs = n.epochs,     learning.rate = learning.rate, min.dist = min.dist, spread = spread,     set.op.mix.ratio = set.op.mix.ratio, local.connectivity = local.connectivity,     repulsion.strength = repulsion.strength, negative.sample.rate = negative.sample.rate,     a = a, b = b, seed.use = seed.use, metric.kwds = metric.kwds,     angular.rp.forest = angular.rp.forest, reduction.key = reduction.key,     verbose = verbose)
 5: RunUMAP.Seurat(my.exp, dims = 1:30)
 6: RunUMAP(my.exp, dims = 1:30)
```

I do not see a reason why it should be getting a `sigfault` here.  I have run this function multiple times over last several months.  This seems to be happening since about a week.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:  I have now restarted the machine one, removed entire older `R` installation, started with a fresh install.  I am still getting exactly same error, including `address 0xffffffffffffffffffa ...`.

Sameet